# Not able to open link in new tab using ctrl + mouse click in testcafe

Tags: testing, tabs, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

```
import { fixture, Selector } from 'testcafe';
 
fixture`Fixture import`.only
    .page('https://testcafe.io/documentation/402634/guides');
 
test('Click a button', async t => {
 
    await t.maximizeWindow()
    const ab = Selector('a[href="/documentation/402837/guides/basic-guides/assertions"]')
    await t.click(ab, {modifiers: {ctrl:true}})
    await t.wait(5000)
});
```

I'm trying to open a link in new tab using ctrl + click, the testcase was getting pass, not throwing any error but the link is opening in the same tab.

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe does not open new windows using the `Ctrl + mouse click` combination. The `ctrl` modifier only sets the `ctrlKey` property of the MouseEvent to `true`.
If you want to open a new window, you can use the `openWindow` method: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402694/reference/test-api/testcontroller/openwindow

Comment: In my current application there is a scenario where, with normal click on hyperlink - the Link has to be open in same window and with 'ctrl + click' the same link has to be open in different window (this is the requirement from the user). How can I automate this  scenario? using testcafe.!!

Comment: The `Ctrl+click` action is the default browser behavior, and TestCafe is not intended to test the default browser behavior. This usage scenario is supposed to work in your browser, so it should not be tested by TestCafe.